# How can I implement path finding with obstacles between cells?

Tags: path-finding

I'm trying to make a game at the moment and have some trouble with the A* algorithm for path finding.

[image]

In the picture the orange and rainbow cells are walkable, but the orange cells have walls around them that should not be crossed. I don't know how to define these walls for my A* algorithm.

So my player is going over the wall to get to the point (red path) but I want it to avoid the wall (green path).

I'm currently using this library: [astar-javascript](https://github.com/bgrins/javascript-astar) but I can't define "special" cells with it that could be crossed on one side only.

If anyone has an idea, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Two cells are connected iff they are adjacent and there is no wall between them.  After that, A* works as normal.

If your path-finding library doesn't support defining adjacency like that *(which seems unlikely, they usually support generic graphs)*, you can use [this trick](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/142525/2061) to turn thin-walls into full cells.

Comment: Or heck, you can use raycasts to find the walls and populate a datastructure that handles adjacency with the results.

Answer (score 2):

This library appears to use an adjacency matrix, with a value of 0 denoting a wall.  See this line in the library's readme:

> 1. A weight of 0 denotes a wall.

What you want then in order to denote a wall between cells 1 and 2 is a matrix where matrix[1][2] and matrix[2][1] are both 0.  More documentation for the adjacency matrix model is easily accessible online, but I cannot easily link it as I am on mobile.